# Does Clash of Clans have a building that allows troops to defend your base?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Are there any buildings that allow you to store trained troops in it, of which will then be used to defend your base if someone attacks?

*There's another game that offers a similar mechanic, from Backyard Monsters, called a "Monster Bunker", where players can spend 'Putty' (a resource currency) to store created troops to defend the base, and are killed off if killed while defending.

Wiki page: http://backyardmonsters.wikia.com/wiki/Monster_Bunker*

**Does Clash of Clans have a mechanic like this?** one that allows players to store **their own** troops as defense?
*Or are clan troop donations (which are stored in the Clan Castle) the closest thing to this?*

Comment: I have never played CoC, but I have played Samurai Siege (*very* similar), and they also have a temporary "Mercenary Camp" (as well as the Clan Castle variant) you can build once you have collected certain loot from attacking other players. Not sure if this is the same case in CoC.

Comment: Make use of castle clan reinforcement for same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are in a clan, and other members of your clan donate troops to you, they will be stored in your clan castle and come out for defense. This is the only way that I know of to defend with troops. So no, you can't train troops and use them for defense. However, others may donate troops that you can use for defense.
Also, skeleton traps may be considered troops by some, even though they are not trained.

Comment: +1 but it doesn't answer my question. *(Try adding a: "No, there isn't any other possible way than for people to donate troops to your clan castle." or a "Yes, you can try doing [what to do].")*

Comment: @aytimothy it answered the question before you edited it. you should not do this. please accept his answer

Comment: +1 I will also add that skeleton traps are kind of troops, but only skeletons. Also heroes will defend your village if set to defending. They loose health when attacked. This means that if it is critical that they are available for war when you return, you can set them to not defend.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to self donate.

You can store your **own troops** in your clan castle if you have multiple accounts and donate to yourself ***from your other account***(s).

By the way, one good reason to join a clan is that clans with higher experience (Experience level 5 and up) can donate stronger troops - and so can you.  For example if you are in my clan and I give you my Level 5 giant, it becomes an Level 6 giant for you. Using this clan perk my TH9 account can give my TH7 account max Giants (Level 7) and max Dragons (Level 5).

The [Clan Perks](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/567168-Full-information-on-Clan-Levels-and-Perks) are described in SuperCell's documentation and even in the game.

Answer (score 0):

No,in there isn't any other possible way than for people to donate troops to your clan castle  .

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course,

the skeleton trap is the defence that can summon troops(skeletons) that may change the wave of the battle.

Assume a situation of giants attacking your base. 3 skeleton traps concentrated at 3 adjacent tiles the giants would spring up 3 x (4 skeletons) = 12 skeletons to attack giants. the giants ignore such troops so skeletons will eventually kill giants .(provided there are no other troop attacking those skeletons)

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, there is... But only for the Builder Base.

[image]

The [Guard Post](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Guard_Post) allows you to station defensive troops in your Builder Base. Unlike the Bunker or Clan Castle however, the troops that are stationed there are tied to the building's level, rather than donations or the troops you have unlocked/upgraded.